# boto3: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, boto3

I try to test  boto3 library as documented http://boto3.readthedocs.io/ web page. I try to get Cloudformation stack list. So my code is:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('cloudformation')
response = client.list_stacks(
    NextToken='string',
    StackStatusFilter=[
          'CREATE_IN_PROGRESS'|'CREATE_FAILED'|'CREATE_COMPLETE'|'ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS'|'ROLLBACK_FAILED'|'ROLLBACK_COMPLETE'|'DELETE_IN_PROGRESS'|'DELETE_FAILED'|'DELETE_COMPLETE'|'UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS'|'UPDATE_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS'|'UPDATE_COMPLETE'|'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS'|'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED'|'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS'|'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE'|'REVIEW_IN_PROGRESS',

    ]
)   
print response
```

When I run this, I receive an error message like:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'
```

Anything wrong with that? I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: Replace the "|" with ",". Actually, you can remove StackStatusFilter entirely since you are including all possible values - not filtering.

Comment: Also remove the NextToken parameter. This is used when you have to call list_stacks() multiple times for truncated listings. Do not  include this parameter on the first call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're including the pipe symbol (`|`) when you shouldn't be. The syntax they give you on the boto3 docs is just showing you all of the possible filter terms. You need to separate the possible statuses with commas, not pipes. Alternatively if you want *all* cloudformation stacks, you can just omit the `StackStatusFilter` parameter